# WindowsPhone | How get file from isolated storage to my machine

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I need to get video that has been recorded by my app to isolated storage.

Is this possible?

Or I should save my recorded video to some 'shared' place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to get a file of an app that you have deployed on your device (that is not installed from the windows store), you can use the command line tool [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which is installed with the windows phone SDK, or if you want a User interface you can use [IsoStoreSpy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/).